# Azure Batch for Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, azure

Is there any way to run Excel VBA using a batch service in Azure?

My company has many large Excel VBA engineering calculations that are run on a regular basis. I am looking at ways to run these efficiently, on demand.

My current thought is I could use the Azure Batch service for this.
When I create the batch pool I would use the Windows Desktop image as the base.
But would jobs I submit have access to Excel?

Any pointers on how to make Excel available within an Azure Batch job welcome.
Any better suggestions for another Azure service that might be more appropriate also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Azure Batch is probably your best bet. Do not assume that any Windows desktop OS image will have Excel - there is a smaller subset that also has M365 applications, that would have Excel. Here I would caution you as far as licensing, I have no idea what licensing you have and whether or not it would allow for this use case, or if it would even work in an unattended fashion without a logged-in user. My gut feeling is that if you can make a .bat file or similiar running on a stock Azure image, or your own custom image, do what you want, then Azure Batch should work.

Comment: Here is a reference if you want to go down the path of making your own images: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-sig-images

Comment: A few years ago there was a product for Excel that enabled processing of compute heavy models in the cloud. [This Google Cloud product](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-connector-for-excel) is similar.

Comment: Many thanks to KonTheCat, this is hugely helpful. I have already created a VB Script that starts Excel without a UI, does the required processing, closes the spreadsheet, and exits Excel, so your approach would seem right. I will investigate the available images again, and I note the point about licensing.

Comment: Thanks MT1, I will investigate this option also.